# Checking if a value exists within a sequence

Tags: javascript

I want to check a value is contained in the set `3,8,13,15,18,23,28, ..., etc.`; basically the set is defined by `3 + 5n`.

How can I achieve this with a simple condition?

Code:

```
if(/* condition here */) {
  // value is part of set
} else {
  // value is not part of set
}
```

Comment: what type of variable is it? String? Array? Also, this does appear to have anything to do with JQuery.. just javascript

Comment: its basically an array index that i want to check for if index equals 3,8,13,18,23...if it matches then that array index values i wana print

Comment: Is 15 should be in sequence? If i understood correctly it is unlimited sequence each value of what, differs on 5. Right?

Comment: yes its unlimited sequence each value should defer by 5

Comment: should be tagged fizzbuzz if anything

Answer (score -3, accepted):

jquery has a inarray function. you can use it as follows.

```
var val = $("#item").val();
var arr = [3,8,13,15,18,23,28];

if ($.inArray(val, arr)) {
    //do the code
} else {
   //do other code
}
```

Comment: Where's the jquery tag?

Comment: @Jack it is removed now

Comment: the values i want to check for are not just till 28, but all values that can come after adding 5 to current value, for e.g 28,33,38,43,48 and so on

Comment: Or you can use just arr.indexOf(val)>-1

Comment: @PabloLozano Doesn't work in IE < 9.

Comment: this should not in anyway be the accepted answer, this so much lamer than [3,8,13,15,18,23,28].indexOf(num) > -1

Comment: This is suspicious... Why would you get the value from an html element without any mention of it from the OP? Why would you use JQuery? Are you cheating the rep system? Are you the OP?

Comment: @musefan OP has been a member a lot longer than this guy so I suspect not, it's the OP's fault for being unclear on the requirements I'm guessing.

Comment: the question title says how to do with jquery its not my fault the question title has changed since @musefan

Comment: @musefan your the one who changed the title and removed jquery and what type of drama you trying to start.

Comment: @Zenith check the edit changes of the question musefan was the one who removed jquery

Comment: @DevZer0: I changed the title based on what the OP said he wanted in the comments. And regardless of how you decide to answer. There is absolutely no need for JQuery and the question itself contained no use of JQuery

Comment: i didn't see that thread of communication, i was working under the original question. I am sorry it hurt your feelings i didn't try to get on your territory  @musefan

Answer (score 6):

if you have to check if your variable is in those values which is (3 + 5n), you should use this:

```
var val = 8; //for example
if ((val % 5) == 3) {
//do the code
} 
else {
//do other code
}
```

Comment: now the question has been edited the correct answer

Comment: Due to last comment under question. It is only correct take. Also it is better to use === instead of ==